# Pass an onclick event the id of the calling object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm having to work within an environment in which I cannot use additional frameworks.

I am trying to send the id of a dynamically generated td to a function to be processed.

Looks something like this:

```
'<td id="td' + j + '" class="r' + i + 'c' + j%2 + '" onclick=GetLocation(this)>'
```

I'm just not sure (and cannot find after reading articles for an hour or so) how to pass the object's id. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: if you're the one dynamically generating it, won't you know how to pass it in?  just pass that same string instead of `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you could do the following in your `GetLocation()` function:

```
var GetLocation = function(someObject){
   var objectID = someObject.id;
   alert("the id is -> " + objectID);
};
```

Comment: Also - it might be a good idea to inspect the `td` you are expecting an id from. It could be that it's not being assigned an id. Most major browsers come with an inspector.

Answer (score 0):

If the id is assigned, you could either pass it as `this.id` or just pass `this` itself and access the id inside the function body like `obj.id`